# scheduled node script in crontab doesn't run after reboot

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks

I've scheduled a node script in crontab to run after reboot by adding this line to my /etc/crontab:

```
@reboot /home/eugen/Documents/scripts/tests/run_after_boot/index.js
```

**/home/eugen/Documents/scripts/tests/run_after_boot/index.js** file contains this script, which is supposed to open vscode:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('code', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    //some err occurred
    console.error(err)
  } else {
   // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
   console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
   console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
  }
});
```

After reboot, nothing happens. Also, I tried to add the same line (`@reboot /home/eugen/Documents/scripts/tests/run_after_boot/index.js`) by executing the `crontab -e` command in my terminal, but the same problem appeared: nothing happened after reboot.